# Where Should I Set Environmental Variables For Use By Sublime Text 3

Tags: macos, environment-variables, sublime-text-3

I have a Sublime Text 3 package that will only work if a particular environmental variable is set. The env is currently set in my `.bash_profile`, so if I launch Sublime Text from the Terminal, this env is available to it. I'm on OSX.

However if I don't launch it from the Terminal it isn't.

**So How can I make an environmental variable available to Sublime Text 3?**

Comment: what operating system are you using?

Comment: and what is the package? There may be an option to set the variable in a config file...

Comment: @MattDMo It's unrelated to the package. Just happens that a quirk of my system means that for the package to run a command successfully it needs the Env to be set.

Comment: OK, but the more information you provide the better the answer will be. Can you at least tell us what OS you're using?

Answer (score 1):

use `~/.pam_environment`

This file uses a special format: see http://man.cx/pam_env(5)  ,
http://man.cx/pam_env(8)

Comment: Does this work on OSX? [It isn't listed in the man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/pam_env.8.html).